# Setting up Hyperledger Fabric Application with IBM Cloud

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, ibm-blockchain

I have developed application using Hyperledger Fabric, also have installed Chaincode on IBM Cloud and created channels. I am not sure how can I connect `html` to IBM Cloud (My SDK is ready and all the controllers are set up).

Answer (score 1):

You have to develop your "Client" application and authorize it against the IBM Blockchain Service running your dapp. In this way you can use your chaincode api and execute your transactions. You can find the detailed steps within this IBM doc: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/blockchain/v10_application.html#developing-applications

Comment: @FrankerZ should be detailed enough now. Regards